# Basic Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to learn a bit about PowerShell scripts and have been trying to logically breakdown a script which includes this snippet.

```
$destFolders | Foreach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $Source -dest (Join-Path $_ $destFileName) }
```

If i was writing this from scratch i think i would write it as follows - why am I wrong?

```
$destFolders | Foreach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $Source -dest ($_) }
```

**Full Script:** *- please note $destfilename is not defined, possibly in error(?)*

```
$path = "C:\a\" 
$filename = (get-date).AddDays(-4).ToString('afileMMdd.txt')
$fileexisting = "$path\$filename"
$destfolders = "C:\b\", "C:\c\" 

while(!(Test-Path $fileexisting)) {Start-Sleep 5} 

$destfolders | 
    ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $path\$filename -dest (Join-Path $_ $destfilename)}
```

Comment: You must include the complete script if you expect a proper answer. Please [edit] the question.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Although your question should be asked rather at http://stackoverflow.com/ it could be answered here if you [edit] your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

This line contents elements, such as `$destFolders`, `$Source` and `$destFileName`, that are seemingly part of a full script. Without knowing them and their purpose, my answer could be wrong.

However, the [Copy-Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Copy-Item) command has the ability to copy an item and rename it too. It seems this is exactly what the first line of script is doing. Your line just copies the item.

Comment: Thank you for the response here is the full script. It's the $destFileName that confuses me.     $path = "C:\"
$filename = "myfile.txt"
$destfolders = "D:\", "E:\"

while(!(Test-Path $path/$filename)) {Start-Sleep 5}

$destfolders | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $path\$filename -dest (Join-Path $_ $destfilename)}

Comment: Hmm... Strange. In this script, the line that you have given is different and there is no $destfilename variable. What are we missing?

Comment: Also $path/$filename results in division error. And $path\$filename result in token error. Everything in this "full script" is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Briefly**: `Join-Path` allows you to maintain folder structure providing that `$destFileName` contains directory and file information. (i.e. it looks something like `"somedirectory\myfile.txt"`, not `myfile.txt`)

So the script is copying files from `C:\` drive to `E:\` and `D:\`.

Imagine a file `C:\myfile.txt` exists:

> Copying using both snippets
>   yields the same result: your snippet says "copy from c:\ to d:\ and
>   e:\ I'm not doing anything with the filenames so just keep them the same", the other snippet says "copy from c:\ to d:\myfile.txt and
>   e:\myfile.txt. I am explicitly telling you the filenames"

Imagine you have a file `C:\somedirectory\myfile.txt`

> Now there's a
>   difference as `$_` will copy to `D:\myfile.txt` and `E:\myfile.txt` again. It will ignore the
>   fact the the file was contained inside a directory. Using  `Join-path
>   $_ $destFileName` will mean the file is copied to D:\somedirectory\myfile.txt`and E:\somedirectory\myfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can see a doubled backslash in `C:\a\\a6ile0309.PxP` (minor mistake) and supposedly unwanted characters in original output (severe error):

```
a6ile0309.PxP
 ↑        ↑ ↑
 ↓        ↓ ↓
afile0309.txt
```

The latter is caused by misused format specifiers `f` and `t`

```
(get-date).AddDays(-4).ToString('afileMMdd.txt')
#                                 ↑        ↑ ↑
```

Read [Formatting Dates and Times](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx) and [Formatting Numbers and Dates Using the CultureInfo Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730954.aspx):

- `f` Full date and time (long date and short time)
- `t`, `%t` **The first character in the AM/PM designator** defined in AMDesignator or PMDesignator, if any. Specify "%t" if the format pattern is not combined with other format patterns.

In fact, `f` in `afile` results to last millisecond(?) or tick(?), see last note below. Honestly, I don't know if it can be escaped so try the following code snippet:

```
'--- original ---'
$path = "C:\a\" 
$filename = (get-date).AddDays(-4).ToString('afileMMdd.txt')
$fileexisting = "$path\$filename"
$destfolders = "C:\b\", "C:\c\" 
Write-host $filename, $fileexisting -ForegroundColor Yellow

### next WHILE never ends
### while(!(Test-Path $fileexisting)) {Start-Sleep 5} 

'--- use rather ---'
$path = "C:\a\" 
$filename = 'afile' + (get-date).AddDays(-4).ToString('MMdd') + '.txt'
$fileexisting = Join-Path $path $filename
$destfolders = "C:\b\", "C:\c\" 
Write-host $filename, $fileexisting
```

**Output**:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SU\1187865.ps1
--- original ---
a6ile0309.PxP C:\a\\a6ile0309.PxP
--- use rather ---
afile0309.txt C:\a\afile0309.txt
```

**Please note** that

```
$filename = 'afile' + (get-date).AddDays(-4).ToString('MMdd') + '.txt'
```

could be written as

```
$filename = '{0}{1}{2}' -f 'afile' , (get-date).AddDays(-4).ToString('MMdd') , '.txt'
```

and I don't know which notation is better or more correct (*PowerShellish*).

**Also note** the difference:

```
PS D:\PShell> (get-date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.ffffff")  # six f
2017-03-13-22.23.35.897305

PS D:\PShell> (get-date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.fffffff") # seven f
2017-03-13-22.30.08.4030682

PS D:\PShell> (get-date).ToString("f")
13 March 2017 22:23

PS D:\PShell> (get-date).ToString("ff")
20
```